# SQL Server - sp_rename to change table name

Tags: sql, sql-server, sp-rename

I'm trying to rename a table using `sp_rename` but I am getting the following error when executing the query:

```
DECLARE @DateValue INT
SET     @DateValue = CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE()-1, 112) 

DECLARE @ArchiveTableName VARCHAR(255) 
SET     @ArchiveTableName = 'dbo.tblProductPipeline_'+ CAST(@DateValue AS VARCHAR)


EXEC SP_RENAME 'dbo.tblProductPipeline_Daily', @ArchiveTableName
```

[image: Error Message]

> Msg 15225, Level 11, State 1, Procedure sp_rename, Line 338
>   No item by the name of 'dbo.tblProductPipeline_Daily' could be found in the current database 'Nexus', given that @itemtype was input as '(null)'.

Can anyone please help me with my understanding of what's going wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: [Pinal Dave has a good blog on this](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2016/01/05/sql-server-fix-sp_rename-error-msg-15225-no-item-by-the-name-of-s-could-be-found-in-the-current-database/)

Comment: Don't specify the schema name for @ArchiveTableName. Otherwise, the 'dbo.' will become the part of the table name (i.e. `[dbo].[dbo.tblProductPipeline_20180406]`.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed now - for some reason the table referenced was dropped...